# How do I grep a multi-line postgresql log?

Tags: grep, postgresql, logs

If I need to search for some command in the system logs, this happens:

```
$cat /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log | grep 'UPDATE limit'
8833 2017-02-01 12:31:51 BRST whoami@172.X.X.20 anotherdb LOG:  comando: UPDATE limit
5067 2017-02-02 17:38:27 BRST whoami@172.X.X.20 thisdb LOG:  comando: UPDATE limit
```

But I need the full command, I am trying a lot of commands like pcggrep, agrep, grep, but I am not having any sucess.

The expected result need to be like this (note the number of lines on the query may vary):

```
8833 2017-02-01 12:31:51 BRST whoami@172.X.X.20 anotherdb LOG:  comando: UPDATE limit
                        SET xxx = xxx
                        FROM xxx
                          JOIN xxx ON xxx = xxx AND xxx = xxx
                          JOIN xxx ON xxx = xxx AND xxx = '012017'
                        WHERE xxx = xxx and xxx = 13
5067 2017-02-02 17:38:27 BRST whoami@172.X.X.20 thisdb LOG:  comando: UPDATE limit
                        SET xxx = xxx
                        FROM xxx
                          JOIN xxxx ON xxx = xxx AND xxx = xxx
```

I tried pcggrep and agrep, but they are expecting something like a start pattern or end pattern, but I think I don't have a end pattern, this is the default postgresql configuration in portuguese, but looking by eye, you can see when a new line of the query start by this number 8833 or 5067.

Comment: I usually use `pcregrep -M` (multiline). The devil is understanding regexp, and having \n characters in the regexp too. Try to define a regexp that gets all lines until finding the next date or until a line not starting with blanks/tabs

Comment: I am with something in hands that requires more attention, will try to come back later on.

Comment: Hum another problem, they are not tabs, it just spaces. The default PostgreSQL logs are so hard to handle, i am considering to change the log_format. I think they need to create a directive that forces multi lines queries to go to a single line. Dont you agree?

Comment: Having it in multiples lines make it visually easier on the eyes, having it in one line if possible, makes it easier to grep. At the end of day, it depends on your preferences, and the size of your queries. If I am not wrong, there is a character limit for logs, I remember vaguely something about that.

Comment: (I did not even noticed we were jumping between the question and answer. Glad the solution worked. I am adding something to the answer for you)

Comment: There is a way to make it case insensitive ?

Comment: Yes, case insensitivity is the same as in `grep`, `pcregrep -i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using `pcregrep`try this:

```
pcregrep -iM "^[0-9]+.*UPDATE limit.*\n(^[^0-9].*\n){1,}" /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
```

-i is for case insensitivity;
-M is for multiline;

You can change the string "UPDATE limit" for other type of queries you need to search.

Basically, the regexp is: find all the lines that start with one or more digits, followed by a string, then the query, followed by a string until the end of line, then followed by 1 or more lines (){1,} that do not start with digits [^0-9].

Here is a [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) about extended regular expressions.

Comment: I am trying lets see what happen. Is running for a long time.

Comment: And no, it dit not work, returned nothing =[

Comment: Can you paste a few lines of the log somewhere? It might have to do with formatting...I am changing something.

Comment: Try it now as it is.

Comment: Ok it is processing.

Comment: (Only the explanation of the regexp)

Comment: There is some way to make this fast?

Comment: Depending on the size of file, it could be a little slow. awk should not be significantly faster, you can always do a `tee` to see it while it creates the file...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52984/discussion-between-rui-f-ribeiro-and-luciano-andress-martini).